# Can the Python file object be inherited?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, python-3.8, python-class

I'm interested to know if the Python file object can be inherited. How does this work?
Because flake8 does not like the following:

```
class testClass(file):
```

Instead, it seems that it has to happen like this:

```
class testClass(object):

    def __init__(self, file):

        self.file = open(file)

    def __enter__ (self):
        return self.file

    def __exit__ (self):
        self.file.close()
```

This new method seems quite clunky. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: `file` isn't a plain builtin name…!?

Comment: *... does not like ...* is not a useful or informative comment. What exactly is `file` in `class testClass(file):`?

Comment: and what is the error/warning in flake8?  also pick a language.  `file` exists as a built-in in Python 2 but not in Python 3 so don't tag both.  Since Python 2 is obsolete `python` is sufficient in most cases.

Comment: Something like `class foo(file): pass` works just fine... *in Python 2*. In Python 3, `open` returns not a value of type `file` (because the type `file` doesn't exist), but one of several possible classes (`_io.TextIOWrapper`, `_io.BufferedReader`, etc) depending on how exactly the file is being opened.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've been looking at old Python 2 code and preparing it to work with Python 3. So, I guess "file" used to be a built in as you say. Why is it no longer? It seems very useful to be able to inherit it.

Comment: I tagged both Python 3 and Python 3 but forgot to explain that I'm working on Python 2 code and preparing it for Python 3.

Comment: The flake8 error was: "F821 undefined name 'file'"

Comment: Another question related to this is: if in Python 3 one uses "open", as above, should one use the __enter__ and __exit__ methods, as above, or: try/finally, with respect to the open method?